# ¿Cómo hacer busquedas combinando palabras para obtenerlas de varios campos y tablas relacionados de una bd en Laravel?

Tags: laravel-5, scope

Tengo un scope donde realizo búsquedas en diferentes tablas y campos de una base de datos:

```
public function scopeSearch($query, $search)
{
    if (trim($search) != "")
        return $query->where(DB::raw("CONCAT(title, ' ', street, ' ', city, ' ', first_name, ' ', last_name, ' ', price, ' ', province, ' ', region)"), "LIKE", "%$search%");
}
```

Las tablas están relacionadas y en el controlador las tengo unidas con JOIN, funciona bien si en el input search coloco alguna palabra que está contenido en el título del anuncio, o el nombre de la calle, la provincia, el nombre o el apellido de manera individual y funciona bien, filtra los resultados... Ejemplo: "José", "Bermúdez" "Caracas", "Miranda", "Casa"... Palabra por palabra.

Mi duda es como hago para cuando escriba en el input de la búsqueda "ciudad + provincia" que están separadas me las busque? o "Nombre + Apellido", ejemplo "José Bermudez", "Caracas Miranda", etc. y me traiga resultados la búsqueda.